# c++ program error (fix)

Tags: c++, syntax

Need help fixing this code I am completely new to c++ : i get a expected '}' at end of input error. I stood up  a while today trying to fix this and I am using eclipse on windows 7 , but for all the ideas I have come with none have helped me fix the problem .

```
#include <iostream>
#include  <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{

    // Get seed color
    string seedColor = "";
    cout << "Enter the seed color (red or blue): \n";
    cin >> seedColor;

    // Get temp
    int temp = 0;
    cout << "Enter the temperature (F): \n";
    cin >> temp;


    // Get the soil moisture
    string soilMoisture = "";
    cout << "Enter the soil moisture (wet or dry): \n";
            cin >> soilMoisture;
    // if red seed
    if(seedColor == "red")
    {

        // If temp >= 75
        if(temp >= 75)
        {

        // if the soil is wet
            if(soilMoisture == "wet")
            {
         // output sunflower
                cout << "A sunflower will grow.\n";
            }

        // if the soil is dry
            if(soilMoisture == "dry")
            {
        // output dandelion
                cout << "A dandelion will grow.\n";
            }
        }
        // otherwise
        else
        {
        // output mushroom
            cout << "a nasty mushroom will form!\n";
    }
        // if blue seed
    if(seedColor == "blue")
    {
        // If temp is between 60 and 70
    if(temp >= 60 && temp <= 70)
    {
        // If the soil is wet
    if(soilMoisture == "wet")
    {
        // output dandelion
        cout << "A beautiful dandelion will grow.\n";
    }

        // If the soil is dry
    if(soilMoisture == "dry")
    {
        // output sunflower
        cout << "A sunflower will grow out of the earth!\n";
    }
    }
        // otherwise
    else
    {
        // output mushroom
        cout << "You will produce a mushroom.\n";
        }

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Indent your code correctly and all will become clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** You are not closing correctly both the `if(seedColor == "red")` and `if(seedColor == "blue")` blocks (unless a seed might be at the same time red and blue and some code is omitted at the end, which I assume is not the case).

**Longer and more constructive answer:** you are facing this problem basically because of indentation issues, making it hard for you to visually identify that this is happening. You might get used to do this manually as you write your code, but there are tools for this.
Assuming you are not using a full blown IDE such as Eclipse CDT or visual studio (otherwise indentation would have probably been handled by the IDE already).

As a illustration, your code, corrected and with correct indentation, looks like the following.

```
#include <iostream>
#include  <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    // Get seed color
    string seedColor = "";
    cout << "Enter the seed color (red or blue): \n";
    cin >> seedColor;

    // Get temp
    int temp = 0;
    cout << "Enter the temperature (F): \n";
    cin >> temp;

    // Get the soil moisture
    string soilMoisture = "";
    cout << "Enter the soil moisture (wet or dry): \n";
    cin >> soilMoisture;
    // if red seed
    if (seedColor == "red") {

        // If temp >= 75
        if (temp >= 75) {

            // if the soil is wet
            if (soilMoisture == "wet") {
                // output sunflower
                cout << "A sunflower will grow.\n";
            }

            // if the soil is dry
            if (soilMoisture == "dry") {
                // output dandelion
                cout << "A dandelion will grow.\n";
            }
        }
        // otherwise
        else {
            // output mushroom
            cout << "a nasty mushroom will form!\n";
        }
    }
    // if blue seed
    if(seedColor == "blue")
    {
        // If temp is between 60 and 70
        if(temp >= 60 && temp <= 70)
        {
            // If the soil is wet
            if(soilMoisture == "wet")
            {
                // output dandelion
                cout << "A beautiful dandelion will grow.\n";
            }

            // If the soil is dry
            if(soilMoisture == "dry")
            {
                // output sunflower
                cout << "A sunflower will grow out of the earth!\n";
            }
        }
        // otherwise
        else
        {
            // output mushroom
            cout << "You will produce a mushroom.\n";
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And it is. By the same token the way you are pointing this out would be better, if you would objectively point out the mistakes.

Comment: Now that's the best answer among the answers for this questions. Deserves a +1.

Comment: Thank you , this helped alot.  I have been looking around all day and this answer was just amazing !

Answer (score 0):

You missed (`}`) for if conditions.

One at `if(seedColor == "red")`

and other at `if(seedColor == "blue")`

```
#include <iostream>
#include  <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{

// Get seed color
string seedColor = "";
cout << "Enter the seed color (red or blue): \n";
cin >> seedColor;

// Get temp
int temp = 0;
cout << "Enter the temperature (F): \n";
cin >> temp;


// Get the soil moisture
string soilMoisture = "";
cout << "Enter the soil moisture (wet or dry): \n";
        cin >> soilMoisture;
// if red seed
if(seedColor == "red")
{

    // If temp >= 75
    if(temp >= 75)
    {

    // if the soil is wet
        if(soilMoisture == "wet")
        {
     // output sunflower
            cout << "A sunflower will grow.\n";
        }

    // if the soil is dry
        if(soilMoisture == "dry")
        {
    // output dandelion
            cout << "A dandelion will grow.\n";
        }
    }
    // otherwise
    else
    {
    // output mushroom
        cout << "a nasty mushroom will form!\n";
    }
} // <--
    // if blue seed
if(seedColor == "blue")
{
    // If temp is between 60 and 70
    if(temp >= 60 && temp <= 70)
    {
        // If the soil is wet
        if(soilMoisture == "wet")
        {
            // output dandelion
            cout << "A beautiful dandelion will grow.\n";
        }

            // If the soil is dry
        if(soilMoisture == "dry")
        {
            // output sunflower
            cout << "A sunflower will grow out of the earth!\n";
        }
    }
    // otherwise
    else
    {
        // output mushroom
        cout << "You will produce a mushroom.\n";
    }
} // <--
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This answer helped me alot , loved it. Made it easier for me to understand where I misplaced the '}' .

Answer (score -1):

It isn't really obvious where you forgot the '}'.
e.g it could be before the last else, but also everywhere else.

You should indent your code correctly. Than you'll see your mistake by yourself.